# Can't authenticate SpiderFoot on Kali Linux

Tags: linux

I'm new to SpiderFoot tool and I have Kali Linux on my system and want to use SpiderFoot that has installed by default, for the first time.
But I get an error:

```
Warning: passwd file contains no passwords. Authentication disabled.
Please consider adding authentication to protect this instance!
```

I just read the part about security and authentication in SpiderFoot documentation.

> SpiderFoot will require basic digest authentication if a file named passwd exists in $HOME/.spiderfoot/passwd. The format of the file is simple – just create an entry per account, in the format of: username:password

But I don't know exactly what to do now. please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You've found the answer in the documentation. Create a new user for SpiderFoot by creating/opening the file ~/.spiderfoot/passwd and insert a username and password combination like so:

```
Atena:R34llyStr0ngP@assword!
```

Then restart SpiderFoot and login with those credentials